# How to pass a parameter to a function in casperjs?

Tags: javascript, casperjs

I have stored all the images url in an array, and am trying to test whether image has loaded properly. If you see the below code, i had to repeat few set of lines again and again. How can i write it to be generic?

```
casper.start()
var imagesArray = [];
imagesArray = ['https://www.google.co.in/images/srpr/logo11w.png',
'https://www.google.co.in/images/srpr/logo1w.png']; 

casper.thenOpen(imagesArray[0], function () {
    if (this.currentHTTPStatus === 404) {
        this.warn(imagesArray[0] + ' is missing (HTTP 404)');
    } else if (this.currentHTTPStatus === 500) {
        this.warn(imagesArray[0] + ' is broken (HTTP 500)');
    } else {
    this.echo(' is okay (HTTP %s)');
    }
});

casper.thenOpen(imagesArray[1], function () {
    if (this.currentHTTPStatus === 404) {
        this.warn(imagesArray[0] + ' is missing (HTTP 404)');
    } else if (this.currentHTTPStatus === 500) {
        this.warn(imagesArray[0] + ' is broken (HTTP 500)');
    } else {
    this.echo(' is okay (HTTP %s)');
    }
});


casper.run(function() {
this.echo('Image loading test finished');
this.exit();
});
```

I tried the below method, calling a function but its throwing parser error, what am i doing wrong, or how can i proceed with it?

```
function checkImages(item){
if (this.currentHTTPStatus === 404) {
this.warn(item + ' is missing (HTTP 404)');
} else if (this.currentHTTPStatus === 500) {
this.warn(item + ' is broken (HTTP 500)');
} else {
this.echo(' is okay (HTTP %s)');
}
}

      casper.thenOpen(imagesArray[0], function () {
    this.evaluate(checkImages(imagesArray[0]));
    });

      casper.thenOpen(imagesArray[1], function () {
    this.evaluate(checkImages(imagesArray[1]));
    });
```

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 4):

Since all `then*` function are asynchronous step function that insert a step into the queue, you can call them in a loop. Since `imagesArray` is a native array, it can be iterated over by using `Array.prototype.forEach` which PhantomJS supports:

```
var imagesArray = [
    'https://www.google.co.in/images/srpr/logo11w.png',
    'https://www.google.co.in/images/srpr/logo1w.png'
]; 

casper.start();

imagesArray.forEach(function(imageUrl){
    casper.thenOpen(imageUrl, function () {
        if (this.currentHTTPStatus === 404) {
            this.warn(imageUrl + ' is missing (HTTP 404)');
        } else if (this.currentHTTPStatus === 500) {
            this.warn(imageUrl + ' is broken (HTTP 500)');
        } else {
            this.echo(' is okay (HTTP %s)');
        }
    });
});

casper.run();
```

A simple for loop would have sufficed, but then you would have a problem with the `imagesArray[i]` inside of `thenOpen`. The `i` variable would never change, because every step is executed after the loop finished executing. So every `imagesArray[i]` would show the last url. Because JavaScript has function level scope the url bound to each iteration and never changes afterwards.

Comment: how would this change if I am getting the `imagesArray` inside a `casper.then`, in that case the casper.thenOpen always seems to be called with the last element?

Comment: @srrvnn It wouldn't. There is probably a little difference between this code and that which you tried. You can ask a new question if you still have a problem after debugging. Note the last paragraph of my answer (are you using a for-loop?).

Comment: you are right. i tried the forEach after reading your last paragraph and it works fine.  thank you.

Answer (score 0):

As a reminder, think of the evaluate() method as a gate between the CasperJS environment and the one of the page you have opened; everytime you pass a closure to evaluate(), you’re entering the page and execute code as if you were using the browser console. So you can't use `evaluate` on `checkImages`.

Use `echo` like this :

```
casper.thenOpen(imagesArray[0], function () {
    this.echo(checkImages(imagesArray[0]));
});

casper.thenOpen(imagesArray[1], function () {
    this.echo(checkImages(imagesArray[1]));
});
```

Answer (score 0):

You don't have any need for `thenOpen` in this test case, since you only want to verify response code. you CAN do it that way, but it's incredibly wasteful of time/resources. this is how I achieved the same goal:

```
casper.test.begin('link tester', 73, function(test) {
  casper.start(url);

getLinks = function(){
     links = this.evaluate(function(){
        var links = document.getElementsByTagName('a');
        links = Array.prototype.map.call(links,function(link){
            return link.getAttribute('href');
        });
        return links;
    });
}

casper.then(getLinks);

casper.then(function(response) {
  for (q = 0; q < links.length; q++) {
    if (response == undefined || response.status >= 400) {
      this.test.fail("URL " + links[q] + " failed with response code " + (response.status));
    } else {
      this.test.pass((response.status + " ---- " + links[q]));
    }
  }
});
```

the only caveat with this would be that you can only have 1 failure per casper function. if you are testing 100 URLs on a page, and you fail on the 4th one, you will have to fix that one before you can see if the others failed. thus, you would need to nest a `casper.then()` within your if statement. In case you were wondering, it would look like this:

```
casper.then(function(response) {
  links.forEach(function(link){
    if (response == undefined || response.status >= 400) {
      casper.then(function() {
        this.test.fail("URL " + link + " failed with response code " + (response.status));
      })
    } else {
      this.test.pass((response.status + " ---- " + link));
    }
  });
});
```

Comment: PhantomJS supports `Array.prototype.forEach`, but it could have been solved with by using an IIFE inside of the for loop body. This looks better I think.

Comment: I don't understand why you think this solves the problem. Can you elaborate? Maybe you forgot something. You first retrieve all links from the page. Then you iterate over all links, but you still are on the same page and you don't open the page that you want to check. So, if the start page failed to load every link should fail, but since the start page failed, there is no link to check and you will get 73 dubious test cases.